# YouTube Iframe API player.getVideoLoadedFraction() doesn't update when video is paused

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

The timeline bar on the default player's controls shows buffered video progress when the video is paused but when I try to retrieve that information using the JavaScript API the number never changes from the moment the video was paused.

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround to this?